# Solution to complex equation with conjugate squared

Tags: complex-numbers

Say we have the equation

$$(\overline{z})^2=1$$

How do we solve this for $z$

Comment: Can you solve the equation $w^2=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(\overline{z})^2=\overline{(z^2)}$, it is easy to see that

$$(\overline{z})^2=1$$
$$\iff\overline{(z^2)}=1$$
$$\iff z^2 = 1$$
$$\iff z=\pm 1$$

It is true in general that if $P$ is a polynomial with real coefficients, then $\overline{P(z)}=P(\overline{z})$ for all $z$. This is false if $P$ has a nonreal coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. The given equation is equivalent to
$$(\overline{z})^2-1=(\overline{z}-1)(\overline{z}+1)=\overline{(z-1)(z+1)}=0.$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

let $$z=x+iy$$ then we have $$(x-iy)^2=1$$ or
$$x^2-y^2-1-2xyi=0$$
so we get
$$x^2-y^2=1$$ and $$2xy=0$$
can you solve this?